# Where to find the php_apc accelerator for [Xampp, Wampp] for Symfony2 apps works faster?

Tags: symfony, caching, xampp, wamp, apc

Recently I downloaded from http://symfony.com/download the latest version (**v 2.7**) and among the requirements for setting a robust **dev** environment is necessary to enable or install accelerators.

Where to find a binary compiled and the step-by-step needed, for **Php 5.5** or **5.6** sufficient enough to deal with **Xampp** or **Wampp** servers and fix the missing dependency?

Answer (score 1):

You must have a look into these articles, they helped me a lot:

[Step-by-Step](http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/installing-apc-for-php-5-5)

[APC available download](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/apcu/)

[Latest APCu](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/apcu/4.0.7/)

It should look as this:

[image]